# How can a simple JS object contain spurious properties, since I cannot observe that?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, javascript-objects

While talking about the advantages of `Map` over plain old JS objects, MDN [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

> An `Object` has a prototype, so there are default keys in the map that could collide with your keys if you're not careful. As of ES5 this can be bypassed by using [`Object.create(null)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), but this is seldom done.

This is a thing people typically warn against in the Internet. (Another often recommended solution is to have a `hasOwnProperty` check each time the object's keys are iterated over).

I have a trouble with understanding this issue, given I cannot observe it.

See the below snippet - no spurious properties seem to manifest even though I did not create my 'map' via `Object.create(null)`! (Neither am I using an actual `Map` nor including `hasOwnProperty` checks.)

```js
const dict = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

document.body.innerHTML = `<pre><code></code></pre>`

for(const key in dict) {
  const entry = `dict['${key}'] == ${dict[key]} // true\n`
  document.querySelector('code').textContent += entry
}
```

When and how can the issue MDN docs are warning about manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when the prototype of the object has been modified, like a lot of libraries used to do in the past. You used to have code like: `Array.prototype.merge = function() {};`. Hence these days the advice is to never adjust native prototypes, but to subclass/extend the object first. For example `class MyObj extends Object`.

```js
Object.prototype.serialize = function() {};

const dict = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

document.body.innerHTML = `<pre><code></code></pre>`

for(const key in dict) {
  const entry = `dict['${key}'] == ${dict[key]} // true\n`
  document.querySelector('code').textContent += entry
}
```